# Getting no data when converting Python API call to Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, api

This is going to be a very generic question, so apologies in advanced. I have a python API call that I am trying to 'convert' to JS and HTML so I can create a dashboard with the data. What it does is display one numerical piece of data which we may assume is "500".

Here is my Python class which works perfectly:

```
url = 'https://someURL'

headers = {
    "Authorization":"Bearer XXXX-XXXX", 
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
result = r.json()
print(result['Power'])
```

This returns a number from the API. Again, let's pretend it's "500". Now ere is my attempt at the JS: **mainJS.js**

```
var app = angular.module('tabletApp',[]);

app.controller('tabletCtrl',function($scope, $interval, $http){


    var dataType = "json";

    $scope.getData = function(){

      var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: "https://XXXX",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization':'Bearer XXXX',
        data: postBody
      };

       $http(req).then(function(response) {
        var data = response.data.result['consumptionPower'];

         $scope.kw = response.data.result['consumptionPower'];
         $scope.cost = calculateTouCost($scope.kw);
       },
       function(data) {
             console.log(data);
       });
    }

    $scope.getData();
    $interval($scope.getData,10000);
});
```

And here is the supporting HTML to display the data in a webpage. **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="mainJS.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="black" ng-app="tabletApp" ng-controller="tabletCtrl">
    <div class="container center" class="black" >
        <center><p><b><h1>ACTIVE WATTS FROM API: {{kw}}</h1></b><p></center>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check the network tab in the developer console to verify the XHR is as expected. Set breakpoints, check if variables are assign as expected. Step through the code. Find which line deviates from expectation.